# iOS in-app purchases Automatically purchase after restore completed

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, payment, restore

I'm testing in-app purchases with sandbox. In paymentQueue updateTransactions method I catch to transaction states then if state purchase or restore I try to unlock content(user has been subscribed then turn mode to Premium).

so far everything is works perfectly. The user would be purchase item, then user goes to Premium mode. If user removed application from his device, restore case also works and turn mode to premium.

But somehow, After user clicked to restore button in that time no issue occurs. But if user close to app then open twice user would see a purchased cases again. Some purchase cases works again without any purchase attempt.

I understand is that after adding SKProductQueue observer updatedTransaction method calling. Then somehow purchase case is works.

It's very hard to describe what I'm getting into but basically after user clicked to restore button next time updatedTransaction method work suddenly and purchased case works.Also I will put buy and restore functions but these are correct it seems like.

Any idea would be grateful!

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
          print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        switch transaction.transactionState {


        case .purchasing  : break

        case .purchased:

            // set true for premium mode then turn back to main screen from purchase screen.
             UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "isUserSubscribe")
             UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                getBackMainScreenProvider.Instance.returnMain()
             print("purchased")
             queue.finishTransaction(transaction)

             break

        case .failed:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
              // this case is works more than once but if user has more than purchase 
            // but its okay.
             UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "isUserSubscribe")
             UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
             getBackMainScreenProvider.Instance.returnMain()

             AppDelegate.restoreClickFlag = true

            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)


            break

        default : break
        }
    }

}


 func purchase (product: IAPProduct) {

     guard let productToPurchase  = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first else { return }
     let payment  = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)  // request to the  Appstore in order to   payment process
    paymentQueue.add(payment)
    print("nasıl...")

}

func restorePurchases () {

    print("restoring purchases...")

    paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()

}
```

Comment: Nobody can answer your question since they don't know what you are doing with UserDefaults.

Comment: @ElTomato I tell the whole story, But If you don't want to get anything that's your problem. I'm storing boolean value that contains  user have purchase. After that application turn to premium mode but I'm already saying that's not issue occurs. Everything is working perfectly. Problem not about premium mode.updatedTransaction function works unexpectedly after user has been restored. It's the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend saving `isUserSubscribe` in `UserDefault`s... It is strongly advised that you use keychain instead. `UserDefault`s is no where near as safe (and so jailbroken devices will easily be able to subscribe for free).